# TCPDF -> How to style with CSS

Tags: php, html, css, pdf, tcpdf

I want to style my `PDF` file that I created with `TCPDF`. The class doesn't seem to support many styling's. I would like the style to be like `left: 10px;` and others like that. Does anyone have a solutions for this issue?

I'm styling now with a table, what is not very handy. Can anyone help me out?

Comment: Look at this link: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19002634/how-to-use-external-css-in-tcpdf-pdf-generation

Comment: Duplication of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19002634/how-to-use-external-css-in-tcpdf-pdf-generation.

Comment: So if i use get_file_contents(), i can also use HTML5?

Comment: I assume so @DonnyvanV, give it a go and find out.

Answer (score 0):

I have served many of my hours and find that TCPDF does not support padding and margin properties of css. TCPDF support very limited version of css.

Answer (score -1):

Your question is a bit vague but i think you want to try using a margin or a padding.

It also depends on what u want.

Since you are talking about a class i am expecting you are using div's?

If you are using div's you have to use a margin or padding inside that class.

For the word div class you should put your own class name.

The dot says its a style for a class and a # would apply to an ID.

if u only want 10 px you should figure out which one you want to use.

if u want to use both you should use 5px for padding and margin

For example

```
.div class{
    padding-left:10px;
    margin-right:10px;
}
```

Comment: I really want to down vote this simply for the layout of your answer. Mother of god... -*takes shades off*-